# Do ServiceStack Swift plugin runs on Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, servicestack

After upgrading to Xcode 6.2, the ServiceStack plugin stopped working. Can't add or update reference. Any quick remedies i can apply to continue testing and working?

I'm not sure if this is a good place to ask such question.
In the future where should i flag out ServiceStack Swift Reference issues?

Comment: We'll investigate this issue thx, in the meantime you can still access the Swift types at `/types/swift` e.g. http://techstacks.io/types/swift then you can just save that in a file with a name like `FileName.dtos.swift` (essentially what the plugin does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Apple changed its plugin compatibility UUIDs for Xcode 6.2. You also might find other plugins you have had installed since before 6.2 might stop working for the same reason. For example, you might need to [update Alcatraz](https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/issues/203) as well if you use it.

ServiceStackXCode has been updated and is [now available to install for Xcode 6.2](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Swift/raw/master/dist/ServiceStackXcode.dmg).

If you do come across issues in the future with the plugin, issues can be raised at one the [ServiceStack issues list on Github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues).

Let us know if you are still having problems after the update.

Hope that helps :)